# How do I handle overloading chrome and firefox memory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am working on building a webapp, that loads large csv's, ~1 million rows by 15 columns, but when loading them in chrome and firefox either crash, freeze, or say they're out of memory.

Currently, I'm using PapaParse.js to load in the csv's and performing a few functions and then graphing with d3.js, but often times the browser stops working while I'm loading in data.

I've looked for memory leaks and it seems that number of dom elements is stable, so I don't think thats the problem, but I'm confused as to how to fix this.

Any advice on re-adjusting the browser settings, parsing the csv's differently, or similar issues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There was a discussion about that on the WHATWG mailing list not long ago. I think the conclusion was "you can't" (more precisely, you can't really detect when the browser is out of memory from your code). There may be way to reduce your memory footprint preemtively.

Comment: If you remove all your visualization (d3) code, how much memory does your page end up taking if it finishes loading?

Comment: After loading the page it was 25,000kb, while loading the first dataset it reached 900,000 kb. After loading the first dataset it settled at 500,000 kb. When loading the second dataset it reached 1.8gb. This seems really high right?

Comment: I think chrome generally crashes after 2gb and firefox is 3gb, do you know of any way to raise these thresholds?

Comment: No. But now you can divide the used memory by the number of rows loaded to find out how much a row takes, and you can repeat the experiment to measure improvements in your code. 1.8Gb for 1 million rows, is it? that's 1.8kb per row, seems a bit high, doesn't it? what do the rows look like, structurally, after parsing?